# How to download a file that is stored in SQL Server database as a varbinary type using Angular 7?

Tags: c#, sql-server, angular, typescript, download

I am trying to download a file that is stored in sql server database table as a vrabinary type using typscipt angula 7

I am able to get the object (res) that has fileName and fileContent as a varbinay type from the database

```js
 public download = (fileId) => {
   
      this.fileService.getFilediaById(fileId)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        if (res != null)
        {
          
          const data = res.fileContent; // of type varbinary
          const filename = res.fileName;
          const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
          this.fileUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        }

      },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

```html
<a [href]="fileUrl" [download]="fileName" mat-menu-item (click)="download(fileId)">Download</a>
```

but the file comes empty with error "Failed - No file"

Thanks

Comment: `window.open(this.fileUrl, '_blank')` try this

Comment: Hi, @JohnVelasquez I tried it but it didn't work. It gives an error that says (ERROR TypeError: _co.alert is not a function)

Comment: On which part of the line did you add the code

Comment: Hi, @JohnVelasquez I added the code after the line that says "this.fileUrl = this.sanitizer.by...."

Comment: can you include a screenshot of the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191995/discussion-between-ayoub-and-john-velasquez).